# Pros and cons of using a Thread or TimerTask for an Android game

Tags: java, android

Many Android game examples utilize a Thread to run a game engine on a particular interval. However, I've seen some other examples that use a TimerTask to run the game engine interval as well. I'm curious as to what other developers think the pros and cons of each approach are.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a TimerTask results in a thread being created, so I guess the difference would be one is explicitly a thread where the other is implicitly a thread.

Answer (score 2):

Timertask is a wrapper for a thread that <strike>provides a callback to the main thread</strike> allows you to schedule the running of a runnable sometime in the future. They have fairly different use cases. If you need to run code now, then use a thread, if you need to schedule something to run in the future, use timertask.

*Edit*: My mistake, was thinking of a different class. Fixed

Comment: what is the callback method? unless I am missing something the only public methods on TimerTask are run() cancel() and scheduledExecutionTime()